# How to change the size of individual legend label size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

As shown in the figure, the same font size for Greek letters seems smaller than normal characters. I want to make them looks the same size, how to achieve this?

[image]

The code of the graph is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
gamma=np.sin(2*np.pi*alpha)
x=alpha
y=np.cos(2*np.pi*x)
plt.plot(x,y,label=r'cosine function')
plt.plot(alpha,gamma,label=r'$\gamma=\sin(\alpha)$')
plt.legend(loc=0,fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little bit of a trick to this. Scroll down to the end if you're just interested in the solution.

`plt.legend` returns a `Legend` object with methods that allow you to modify the appearance of the legend. So first we'll save the `Legend` object:

```
legend = plt.legend(loc=0, fontsize=20)
```

The method we are looking for is `Legend.get_texts()`. This will return a list of `Text` objects whose methods control the size, color, font, etc. of the legend text. We only want the second `Text` object:

```
text = legend.get_texts()[1]
```

The `Text` object has a method called `Text.set_fontsize`. So let's try that. Altogether, the end of your code should look like:

```
legend = plt.legend(loc=0,fontsize=20)
text = legend.get_texts()[1]
text.set_fontsize(40)
```

And this is what we get:

[image]

Hm. It looks like *both* of the legend entries have been made bigger. This certainly isn't what we want. What is going on here, and how do we fix it?

The short of it is that the size, color, etc. of each of the legend entries are managed by an instance of a `FontProperties` class. The problem is that the two entries share the same instance. So setting the size of one instance also changes the size of the other.

The workaround is to create a new, independent instance of the font properties, as follows. First, we get our text, just as before:

```
text = legend.get_texts()[1]
```

Now, instead of setting the size immediately, we get the font properties object, but then make sure to *copy* it:

```
props = text.get_font_properties().copy()
```

Now we make this *new, independent* font properties instance our text's properties:

```
text.set_fontproperties(props)
```

And we can now try setting this legend entry's size:

```
text.set_size(40)
```

## Solution

The end of your code should now look like:

```
legend = plt.legend(loc=0,fontsize=20)
text = legend.get_texts()[1]
props = text.get_font_properties().copy()
text.set_fontproperties(props)
text.set_size(40)
```

Producing a plot looking like

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer! Not only give the solution, but also teach you how to think.